# Using EfficientNetB0 - Error - AttributeError: module 'keras.utils' has no attribute 'get_file'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Loading efficient net as below :

```py
import efficientnet.keras as efn
from tensorflow.keras import layers 
from tensorflow.keras import Model 
base_model = efn.EfficientNetB0(input_shape = (224, 224, 3), include_top = False)
```

and getting below error :

> AttributeError: module 'keras.utils' has no attribute 'get_file'

Answer (score 1):

The above posted code is still not working. So, using a workaround for now -

```
import efficientnet.tfkeras as efn
base_model = efn.EfficientNetB6(input_shape = (224, 224, 3), include_top = False)
```